# Solve for $x$ in the following inequality

Tags: polynomials

$2x+x^3+7\gt0$ I have no idea what to do here, because my level of knowledge goes up to binomials and such. Thank you

Comment: Start with $x^3+2x+7=0$.  What happens from there?

Comment: Note that $f'(x) = 3x^2 + 2 >0$, it implies that the function is increasing. Then $f(x) > f(x_0) = 0$, where $x_0$ is a solution of $f$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: Solve by substituting $x$ with $y+\frac{a}{y}$ and you will solve for $a$ later on.